# Как поделить число нацело в javascript?

Tags: javascript

1. Как в javascript поделить число нацело?
2. Есть ли какой-то оператор для деления нацело?

Comment: никак, можно только взять целое от результата

Comment: я понимаю, можно ли увидеть развернутый ответ с примерами кода, как на английском stackowerflow?

Comment: Частный случай _Как поделить число нацело_ - специфицируется меткой [tag:javascript] поэтому не нужно было добавлять еще одно упоминание непосредственно в заголовок. [обсуждение на мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BB-%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0/610#610)

Comment: @Grundy метка "javascript" не решит проблему с уникальными заголовками, я добавил свой ответ по теме на которую вы дали ссылку выше.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Поделить на число без остатка в JS можно несколькоми способами.

**Способ 1.** Округление:

```
var x = 10, y = 3.3333;
alert(Math.floor(x/y));
```

> Этот способ расчитан на результат вычисления больше нуля. Если результат будет отрицательный, то такая конструкция сработает не правильно.

Например :

```
Math.floor(-100/3); // Выдаст -34, хотя целая часть от -33,33333336 будет равна -33
```

Как вариант, для решения этой задачи округлением можно использовать опертор if:

```
if(x/y>=0)
   alert(Math.floor(x/y));
else
   alert(Math.ceil(x/y));
```

**Способ 2 :**
Вероятно не такой быстрый как предыдущий, но более универсальный. Приведение к int:

```
var x = 10, y = 3.3333;
alert(parseInt(x/y));
```

**Способ 3**. Производительный и универсальный:

```
var x = 10, y = 3.3333;

function div(val, by){
    return (val - val % by) / by;
}

alert(div(x, y));
```

**Ну и немного хадкора:**

```
alert(~~(x/y)) // сокращенный Math.floor() результаты будут такие же
alert(x/y>>0)       
alert(x/y|0)
```

демо на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrpub69d/3/)

Answer (score 8):

В javascript отсутствует деление на целые числа и числа с плавающей запятой.
Возможно, как следствие, отсутствуют и специальные арифметические операторы для целых чисел.

Исходя из этого есть несколько вариантов решения:

1. **Выполнение обычного деления и взятие от результата целой части.** Для этой процедуры есть функции [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) и [Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil), разница заключается в том, большее целое или меньшее будет выбрано.

   ```js
   console.log(Math.floor(10 / 3));
   console.log(Math.floor(-10 / 3));

   console.log(Math.ceil(10 / 3));
   console.log(Math.ceil(-10 / 3));
   ```

   Как видно из примера, для положительных чисел подходит `floor`, для отрицательных `ceil`
2. **Использование битовых операций.** На уровне спецификации, указано, что битовые операции работают **только** с 32х-битными целыми числами, поэтому при работе с ними стоит быть осторожным: *при применении их к большим числа, старшие биты числа будут обрезаны*. При этом это позволяет быстро брать целую часть, за счет приведения аргумента к целому числу перед выполнением битовой операции.
   Широко распространенным приемом является применение [побитового или](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) с `0`, что оставляет все биты исходного числа неизменными. А также побитовый сдвиг, так же на 0 разрядов

   ```js
   console.log((10 / 3) | 0);
   console.log((-10 / 3) | 0);

   console.log((10 / 3) >> 0);
   console.log((-10 / 3) >> 0);

   console.log(' Неожиданно: ', (10000000000 / 2) | 0)
   console.log(' Неожиданно: ', (10000000000 / 2) >> 0)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

1. Как вариант деления использовать вот такую конструкцию

   ```
   function divme(a, b){
       return (a - a%b)/b
   }
   ```
2. нет

**UPD:** встречал ещё вариант деления. Возможно будет вам полезна. [Ссылка](http://vispyanskiy.name/ru/tselochislennoe-delenie-v-javascript)

Comment: return (a - a%b)/b -- должно быть правильным ответом :)

Answer (score 2):

Вот ещё вариант:

```
Math.floor(a / b);
```

И вот такой, но с ним лучше быть осторожнее — работает лишь для небольших чисел (где-то до 4e9):

```
a / b | 0
```

Comment: `a / b | 0` интересная запись, как это работает? Возможно это лучше вынести в отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Как я понимаю, для выполнения побитовых операций браузер приводит число к int (целому), при этом сама по себе операция «|0» ни одного бита не изменит. Можно сказать, аналог «(int)doubleValue» в иных языках.

Comment: @Max, с этой операцией стоит быть осторожным, так как при **любых** битовых операциях, входной аргумент обрезается до 32х бит, поэтому результаты могут получаться неожиданными

Comment: понятно, спасибо за то, что разъяснили

Answer (score 2):

Всё зависит от того, как вы хотите округлить результат деления.

```
Math.floor(a/b); 
Math.floor(3/2); // = 1
```

[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

```
Math.ceil(a/b);
Math.ceil(3/2); // = 2;
```

[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

Comment: Целая часть от числа 4.9999 будет число 4

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь функицией Math.trunc(x);

```
Math.trunc(13.37);    // 13
Math.trunc(42.84);    // 42
Math.trunc(0.123);    //  0
Math.trunc(-0.123);   // -0
Math.trunc('-1.123'); // -1
```

[Описание функции на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc)

Comment: конечно понятно в чем дело, но все же вопрос был про деление