# Как работает инструкция If(), если в качестве условия в нём есть несколько выражений?

Tags: javascript

В JS-коде имеется такая функция:

```
function checkVal( num) {
    var val = id('me' + num).value;
    if(isNaN( val ))
        alert(val  + ' не является числом.') 
    else {
        if((function(x) { return (x | 0) === x; })(parseFloat( val)) === (function(x) { return (x | 0) === x; })(parseFloat(String( id(fullScale_0).value))))
            alert('Не верный формат.' + val )
        else
            id('regReading_' + num).value = val;
    }
}
```

Код работает, но я не понимаю логику условия во вложенной инструкции if(). А именно:

1. Почему три логических выражения в условии перечислены без всяких разделителей или логических операторов;
2. Откуда берётся значение "х" в функциональных выражениях function(x).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: где тут три выражения? можете пояснить? а то сложно понять за этой однострочной кашей

Comment: to @u_mulder спасибо за ссылку, но я ни там, ни в других местах не нашел объяснения, как анонимное функциональное выражение работает с параметрами.

Comment: `(function(x) { return (x | 0) === x; })(parseFloat( val))` значит что в качестве аргумента x передается результат `parseFloat( val)`.

Comment: to @АлексейШиманский Я вообще не могу понять, что там и как это работает. Почему то там в условии if() сначала (function(x) { return (x | 0) === x; }), потом без всяких операторов сразу (parseFloat( val)) === (function(x) { return (x | 0) === x; }), а потом так же ещё и (parseFloat(String( id(fullScale_0).value))).

Comment: to @u_mulder т.е. там сравнивается (function(x) { return (x | 0) === x; })(parseFloat( val)) с (function(x) { return (x | 0) === x; })(parseFloat(String( id(fullScale_0).value)))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Откуда берётся значение "х" в функциональных выражениях function(x).

Функция объявляется и сразу вызывается. Такое **[можно делать с функциями](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/IIFE)**

```js
  (function(arg) {
      alert(arg);
  })(666);
//  ^^^^^ сразу вызвали с переданным аргументом
```

> Почему три логических выражения в условии перечислены без всяких разделителей или логических операторов;

Если уметь форматировать код то можно заметить следующее

```
if (

    (function(x) {               |
        return (x | 0) === x;    |  переменная "a"
    })(parseFloat(val))          |
    
    === 

    (function(x) {                                  |
        return (x | 0) === x;                       | переменная "b"
    })(parseFloat(String(id(fullScale_0).value)))   |

)
```

В итоге сводится всё к `if (a === b)`, т.к. говорилось выше, что функции сразу выполняются и получают результат своих действий.

---

Единственно, в самой последней функции в качестве аргумента поступает не "чистый" аргумент, а результат выполнения другой функции, у которой в качестве аргумента идёт ещё одна функция. И получается некая матрёшка:

- выполнится самая первая `id(fullScale_0).value)`
- затем её результат передастся в функцию `String( СЮДА )`
- дальше результат выполнения передастся в `parseFloat( СЮДА )`
- и затем результат передастся в самовызывающуюся функцию

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что инструкция "return (x | 0) === x;" возвращает true, когда x является числом или нулём?

Comment: @NonameNoferstname нулём в смысле null? только когда число или число в строке, типа "123'

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, **целое** число

Comment: @Grundy why? `'1.23' | 0 === 1.23`  валидно и вернёт true

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, потому что скобки надо ставить :) `('1.23' | 0) === 1.23` - вернет false. Без скобок возвращает не `true`, а число `1`.

Comment: Подробнее [тут, в пункте 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/582180/186999)

Comment: @Grundy значит только целое число))

Comment: @NonameNoferstname ↑↑↑